# Problemas con push de git

Tags: git

Hola soy nuevo en git y estoy teniendo problemas con el push, les platico, tengo un servidor donde esta mi sistema en produccion (en mi misma red) al cual aplique un clone en la misma ubicacion donde tengo mi sistema en produccion pero será el sistema de desarrollo. Cuando realizo el push posterior al commit no me da ningun error, incluso reviso el log de git de mi proyecto en produccion y si aparece el cambio pero no se me refleja en mi codigo. Agradecere mucho a quien me ayude con este tema.

Comment: Un push sirve para subir los datos que tienes en tu copia local a la copia del servidor, sin embargo no actualiza el código en las demás copias, solo almacena el cambio. Pasa actualizar el código, en otra copia (supongo que tu copia de producción) tienes que ejecutar un PULL

Comment: Segun lo que he leido al hacer el push si tiene que enviar los cambios con commit al proyecto en produccion

Comment: No sé qué has leído, y no sé qué tienes montado. Pero si no usas algún tipo de sistema de integración continua, NADA va a decirle a tu servidor de producción que tiene que bajarse los cambios. Git es un *"cubo"* donde tú metes código... y el código se queda ahí hasta que alguien va y lo saca, nada más. Git de por si solo, no automatiza absolutamente nada. Cuando haces `push` en una máquina, para actualizar las otras, tienes que hacer `pull`. O eso, o usar algún tipo de sistema CI, pero eso ya es otra cosa, y no tiene que ver con git.

Comment: Como dice la documentación oficial, PUSH _Actualiza referencias remotas usando referencias locales, mientras envía los objetos necesarios para completar las referencias dadas_ [git-push](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push), es decir que actualiza a tu repositorio los cambios confirmado de local a remoto, pero no la copia del código, solo las referencias. Ahora un PULL _Incorpora cambios de un repositorio remoto en la rama actual. En su modo predeterminado_  [git-pull](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)  es decir, que los cambios empujados a remoto son incorporados en la copia.

Comment: En tu caso por lo que interpreto que quieres hacer para **"trabajar en local"**, necesitas una carpeta la cual inicias como repositorio (git init --bare), clonar esa repositorio en la ruta de producción y clonar otro repositorio en la ruta de desarrollo, lo que empujes en desarrollo (push), será jalado, cuando se lo indiques, a producción (pull) y quien manejará esas referencias será el repositorio.

Comment: Es correcto, lo que yo quiero es trabajar local, tengo mi proyecto de produccion y lo clono para tener el proyecto de desarrollo. En el momento que yo haga cambios y los envie con un push quiero que se reflejen esos cambios en mi proyecto de produccion, no sé si guit pueda hacer eso

Comment: Solo con le push no se reflejarán tus datos, es necesario hacer el pull en la copia a producción. Al automático, como dijo Benito-B, necesitas un sistema de integración continua que es diferente a GIT